# The specified network name is no longer available - C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, network-drive

I am trying to read files from different server, using c# console application, but it gives error - "The specified network name is no longer available".

When I ping the server, i am getting a reply, but when I run the exe file of project that has code to access files from server it shows the mentioned error.

The path I am using is in this format: \\xxx.xxx.xx.x\EEE\EEE\FolderName

The code that access/read files:

```cs
public List<string> GetFiles()
{
    List<string> filelist = null;
    string fileFromPath = help.fileFromPath;
    try
    {
        filelist = Directory.GetFiles(fileFromPath).ToList();
        if (filelist.Count == 0)
        {
            log.Error("No file to be processed.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.Message);
    }
    return filelist;
}
```

Where help.fileFromPath has path value and it is stored in app.config

What could be the reason and how could it be fixed?

Comment: You're using an IP address rather than a hostname. It's possible the computer's DHCP lease expired and the address was reassigned to another machine (hence why ping still works). Is there a reason you're not using hostnames?

Comment: Also, please post your code that performs the file copy operation.

Comment: No lease expired is not the case. Even if I try to use hostname, it gives error that - "The network path was not found"

Comment: Even when you use the hostname in Windows Explorer? If that's the case then you have a network configuration issue and your program's crashes are just a symptom of a larger problem.

Comment: I need to ask, but I believe your answer is Yes. Do you have access to the path when you use the Explorer?
If yes, you are getting error when you are debbuging? (did you try to run in administrator mode?)

Comment: @Dai - I can access the server and the files, if I try to access from locally mapped server. but when i am on the server, it gives me error

Comment: @RMH - I am running in administrator mode.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus of firewall software running on the server? This could cause such error.